# What is the PingFederate default admin account?

Tags: pingfederate, pingone

I got the PingFederate running (from the docker image)and I can access the portal but it asks for a username and password.

I find online references that the default account would be "Administrator"/"administrator" or "administrator"/"2Federate", but nothing works.

I also deleted the file /server/default/data/pingfederate-admin-user.xml which should trigger to use the default account but no luck with those 2 credentials above.

Answer (score 0):

After lot of research I found a [guide](https://devops.pingidentity.com/docker-images/pingfederate/) that says that the default account is "administrator"/"2FederateM0re" and that one worked!